# How to properly define Sequelize assocation during data insertion

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying out Sequelize association and I am having an issue.

I have two models

```
class User extends Model { }
User.init(
    {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {/** */ });


class Book extends Model { }
Book.init(
    {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
    }, {/** */ });
Book.belongsTo(User, { as: 'owner' });
```

Imagine, I have the user of the book, how can I associate the user with the book so that I can always get the owner from the book?

I am thinking

```
const user = await User.findByPK(....);
const newBook = Book.create({
        name:"BookName",
        owner:user.id //But this isn't working
    });
```

What is the best way to go about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Defining an association with an alias means `Book` has `ownerId` field.

From the official documentation:

> Defining an Alias is more powerful than simply specifying a custom name for the foreign key. This is better understood with an example:

```js
Ship.belongsTo(Captain, { as: 'leader' }); // This creates the `leaderId` foreign key in Ship.
```

See [Association aliases and foreign keys](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#association-aliases--amp--custom-foreign-keys)

So you should create `Book` like this:

```js
const newBook = Book.create({
        name:"BookName",
        ownerId: user.id
    });
```